# ListView get item id on onClickListener

Tags: android, android-listview

is it possible to get id of an item by setting **OnClickListener** to a **ListView** in android studio?

Comment: You should probably use `OnItemClickListener`

Comment: @Marcus ya i know that method. But is it possible to get the item id by using onClickListener ?

Comment: It might be, but I see no reason to do so.

Comment: @Marcus just curious to know ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `OnClickListener` I would use `OnItemClickListener`.

The callback method looks like this:

```
onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

Where the 4th parameter is the id of your clicked item.

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably implement `OnItemClickListener` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

The method `abstract void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` will give you the position and the id of the row that was clicked